# Buy/Sell indicator with multiple entry conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to create an indicator with multiple filters that can be controlled by toggling checkboxes (on/off). The idea is to generate a buy signal based only on the filters(chekcboxes) that are turned on. for example if checkboxes 1 and 3 are tuned on, then only show those. However, with the code below, when all checkboxes are turned on the indicator works fine, but, when one of them is turned off then nothing shows up.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test", overlay=true)

//Checkboxes
ShowMA1= input.bool(true, "20 EMA")
ShowMA2= input.bool(true, "50 EMA")
ShowMA3= input.bool(true, "100 EMA")
ShowMA4= input.bool(true, "200 EMA")


//Conditions
MA1 = close > ta.ema (close,20)
MA2 = close > ta.ema (close,50)
MA3 = close > ta.ema (close,100)
MA4 = close > ta.ema (close,200)

//output 

BuySignal = (ShowMA1? MA1: na) and (ShowMA2? MA2: na) and (ShowMA3? MA3: na) and nd (ShowMA4? MA4: na)

plotshape(BuySignal, title="BUY", text= "BUY", location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(7, 104, 201), textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code that you set a variable to `na` whenever you want to "turn it off" which can result in:

```
BuySignal = MA1 and MA2 and na and MA4
```

And that `na` will trash your conditionals.

When you have a series of conditions and they are chained together using `AND` then, to turn any of the conditions into a "does not matter" state, you have to turn it into `True`, like:

```
BuySignal = (ShowMA1 ? MA1: true) and (ShowMA2 ? MA2: true) and (ShowMA3 ? MA3: true) and (ShowMA4 ? MA4: true)
```

Now people with from the De Morgan's fan club might tell you that you can further simplify this statement (as `true` is the opposite result of your switches, I highly suggest you don't that. The above code will be perfectly readable after 6 months even if you are drunk.

Cleaner code is not always the best solution:

```
1. BuySignal = (not ShowMA1 or MA1) and (not ShowMA2 or MA2) and (not ShowMA3 or MA3) and (not ShowMA4 or MA4)
2. BuySignal = not (ShowMA1 and not MA1) and not (ShowMA2 and not MA2) and not (ShowMA3 and not MA3) and not (ShowMA4 or not MA4)
```